# Electron limit history goBack in a Webview

Tags: webview, navigation, electron, browser-history

In an electron app I use a Webview showing an external site. I just added two Navigatioàn Buttons and their event handler with:

```
$(document).on( 'click', '#url_back', function(){
  webview1.goBack();
  });
$(document).on( 'click', '#url_forward', function(){
    webview1.goForward();
  });
```

But this site has a login page and so I want to limit my history navigation to the first page after the login. I searched for a way of getting the index but I couldn't find any in the docs.
Further the event which could help me : '`will-navigate`' is documented as not working when using the history API.... (https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#%C3%A9v%C3%A9nement--will-navigate)
So I'm wondering is there is a way of doing so the user doesn't have to log again by clicking back button too many times.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually look better to the docs and find the method `canGoToOffset` which allow to know where we are versus the beginning. So when I'm on the first url after the login I don't do anything on the button click.
so the code for the back button became:

```
$(document).on( 'click', '#url_back', function(){
    if(webview1.canGoToOffset(-2)){
      webview1.goBack();
    }    
    
  });
```